# ng new gives version mismatch warning

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run `ng new myproject`

> Your global Angular CLI version (14.2.3) is greater than your local version (12.2.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Now, I understand if I got this warning when running `ng serve` or `ng build`. But I run `ng new` in an empty directory! Where does `ng` take this local version?

Incidentally, if I create a directory in the root `c:\angtest` and run `ng new` *there* - I don't get a problem. Also, `ng version` gives me v14 there; but v12 in `c:\users\me\sotest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was a folder `c:\users\me\node_modules` (dated about a year ago; so I have no idea when or how I created it) that was used as "local" version when I ran `ng new` is subdirectories of `c:\users\me\*`

Once I deleted it, the problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you are in a directory that contains a `node_modules` folder that has an installed `@angular/cli` already. You can try removing `node_modules` and check if you have a `package.json` in that directory and either remove it or update the `@angular/cli` version.

Comment: thank you @natash -  as I said, it's an *empty* directory.